# Function "select all" and iCheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a "Select all" using [**iCheck**](https://github.com/damirfoy/iCheck/).

This is what I've done so far:

```
$(function () {
    $('input').iCheck();
    $('input.all').on('ifChecked ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'ifChecked') {
            $('input.check').iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $('input.check').iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    });
    $('input.check').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        $('input.all').iCheck('uncheck');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/N7uYR/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/N7uYR/1/)

**I want that when "Check Box 1", "Check Box 2", "Check Box 3", "Check Box 4" are selected, "Select all" also gets selected.**

Exactly like this: [jsfiddle.net/ivanionut/N7uYR/](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanionut/N7uYR/)

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems you already have it implemented; is there anything different from the example code that you want to put in?

Comment: @MathSquared11235 I want to do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanionut/N7uYR/
Look carefully. If I select "Check Box 1" 2, 3, "Check Box 4" will also automatically select "select all"

Comment: The code you have in the "Exactly like this" seems to solve your problem. Why can't you use that code?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
$(function () {
    var checkAll = $('input.all');
    var checkboxes = $('input.check');

    $('input').iCheck();

    checkAll.on('ifChecked ifUnchecked', function(event) {        
        if (event.type == 'ifChecked') {
            checkboxes.iCheck('check');
        } else {
            checkboxes.iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    });

    checkboxes.on('ifChanged', function(event){
        if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == checkboxes.length) {
            checkAll.prop('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            checkAll.removeProp('checked');
        }
        checkAll.iCheck('update');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzul1983/N7uYR/2/)

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still struggling with this, I've altered the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17821003/3061836) from Dzulqarnain Nasir a bit.

I've changed the `removeProp` method to the `prop` method:

```
checkAll.removeProp('checked');
```

Is altered to

```
checkAll.prop('checked', false);
```

The `removeProp`method didn't work for me, but setting the checked property to false worked.

At the time of writing, I'm using iCheck 1.0.2 with jQuery 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

u can use parent of ur checkboxes to do it. for example

```
<div class='allchecked'>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

and using jquery to set attr("checked") or not.

Comment: You wouldn't use `.attr()`, you would use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/): `.prop("checked")`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles across this issue, the accepted answer wasn't working for me on dynamically generated checkboxes.  I found the solution here:

https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/44